# Should i change target sdk version 13 for admob?

Tags: android, admob, proguard

I have an android app, ı using admob. should i changed my target sdk 13 for admob? I heard "you have to changed your target sdk version 13 for Admob". But ı changed target sdk 17 and it worked. And ı have another problem with proguard . When i changed target sdk version 13 from 17 , proguard is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum is 13, so you can use higher sdk versions!

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/

> Make sure you have the latest copy of the Android SDK and that you're
>   compiling against **at least** Android v3.2 (set target in
>   default.properties to android-13).

Comment: my android sdk version is 22.01 , and ı tried it to project.properties proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt and added target sdk 13 , then ı see it "Proguard returned with error code 1. See console" .

Comment: Please read again my answer, the minimum is 13, if your project only works with 17 it is fine!

Comment: and my error ss ; http://imgim.com/target.png when i changed target sdk 17 ,proguard is working fine, i dont give a error. - yes i think my project only work with like 17?

Comment: Yes, it only works on 17... You are using this method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean) which is only available on 17!

Comment: okay i get it, i have will say something ,my project target is 17 but i tested  2.1 , 3.2 , 2.3.3, 4.2.2 it worked fine. ı will add google play is it to be a problem? (min sdk 7)

Comment: This is a whole new question, but the min sdk won't affect you if you are on target 17! The question is already answered, please accept it!